# Template by nested structs in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to write this code, but it produces an error.

```cpp
template<int N>
struct A {
    struct B {

    };
    B f() { return B{}; }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool val = false;

template<int N>
constexpr bool val<typename A<N>::B> = true;
```

```
error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
   13 | constexpr bool val<typename A<N>::B> = true;
```

While this code is working perfectly

```cpp
template<int N> struct A;

template<int N>
struct AB {

};

template<int N>
struct A {
    AB<N> f() { return AB<N>{}; }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool val = false;

template<int N>
constexpr bool val<AB<N>> = true;
```

I understood that C++ would have to check if there exists a `N` such that `T` equals `A<N>::B` when evaluating `val<T>` which is too difficult. That's why there is an error. But my question is: Is there any way of keeping the struct B inside A and defining the value `val<A<N>::B>` for every `N`?

I understand the error if B was defined as a reference to a struct outside A (for instance `using B = int;`) but if B is a struct defined inside A then there is no ambiguity and `N` is easily deduced.

Comment: Your answer was in reality helpful :)

Comment: Not sure what the second code example is testing. Doesn't seem related to your first code. have you tried to template B with <int N> too? Then `template<int N> constexpr bool val<typename A<N>::B<N>> = true;`

Comment: "... such that `T` equals `A<N>::B`" means that if write somewhere in the code `val<int>` the compiler will look at all definitions of val. For the definition `template<int N> constexpr bool val<typename A<N>::B>` the compilers has to check if there exists a value of `N`such that `A<N>::B` is `int`.

Comment: Here is code with assertion which should pass https://godbolt.org/z/d7Grhf5TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide way to retrieve template parameters of `A` from `B`, you might do it by SFINAE/constraint:

```
template<int N>
struct A {
    struct B {
        constexpr static int value = N;
    };
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool val = false;

template <typename T>
requires (std::is_same_v<typename A<T::value>::B, T>) // C++20
constexpr bool val<T> = true;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ez9a3ccET)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to define it outside the class and just have a type alias in the class to use it as normal:

```cpp
template<int N> struct A;

template<int N>
struct AB {
    friend A<N>;
};

template<int N>
struct A {
    using B = AB<N>;
    friend B;
    B f() { return B{}; }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool val = false;

template<int N>
constexpr bool val<AB<N>> = true;
```

There is very little difference between this and a nested `struct B`.

Comment: Passes tests: https://godbolt.org/z/8xo68Pc6b