# How to define an ostream function of an inner struct of a templated outer struct?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, ostream

How can I get this to work? I want to separate the definition and declaration of the friend ostream funciton here.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        T x;
    };
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Inner&);
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Outer<T>::Inner& i) {
    os << "x! " << i.x;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    const Outer<int>::Inner s = {42};
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Adding typename as suggested by the error doesn't work too

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Outer<T>::Inner& i) {
    os << "x! " << i.x;
    return os;
}
```

```
warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Outer<T>::Inner&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
   10 |     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Inner&);
      |                                                                ^
<source>:10:64: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add '<>' after the function name here)
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBSBhtj.o: in function `main':
<source>:24: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Outer<int>::Inner const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: (1) Get rid of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and use the relevant **standard** headers. (2) Try to avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8967610/4165552 - dupe?

Comment: Your 'fixed' code (second snippet) works for me in MSVC. What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: But I guess that's a **linker** error, and we don't have sufficient code to generate that. What does your 'minimal' `main` look like?

Comment: @Sam Apparently, there are major schools and colleges where students are taught to use that header. I'm sure you're aware of [the canonical post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073).

Comment: Added the main entry point!

Comment: are you sure to want `<<` be a friend of `Outer` not of `Inner` ? Though, I always get confused with access of members when nested classes are involved, what you have might be ok already. Is this for ADL, or merely to access the member (which is public in the example, because it is simplified) ?

Comment: Well, with the `main` you've now added and the aforementioned fix, your code builds and runs just fine (that is, when I remove that ugly header and use a real one, instead).

Comment: @AdrianMole not here https://godbolt.org/z/bKfe985Ej

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Outer<T>::Inner& i)
```

`T` is non deducible.

Separate declaration from definition would not be evident.

Simpler would be

```
template <class T>
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        T x;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Inner &i) {
            return os << "x! " << i.x;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: is there a way to make T deducible? I am aware that the inline definition would work but I want to try to separate the declaration and definiton.

Comment: Alternative are more **tricks** than actual solution as templating `operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&) requires (is_inner_v<T>)` with concept/SFINAE to restrict to above type.

Comment: @Jarod42  I suspect the OP would be interested in an example of those tricks ....

Comment: @Jarod42 If it's possible to get the `is_inner_v` trait working, there's another old question trying to solve that very problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516746/template-by-nested-structs-in-c).

Comment: @Peter: Ted Lyngmo provides [link for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516746/template-by-nested-structs-in-c/77003083).